# Problems with Automation and renaming an Azure Database

Tags: database, azure, automation, rename

I am trying to create a RunBook that I can use for renaming an Azure DB for integration test purposes. I have had a look around and there are examples here  but I have still not I have not been able to get any of them to work. 
I am using a Pay-as-you-go subscription and wish to use SQL logins.

I think its getting the correct SQLServerContext that is failing, though I cannot see see what I should be doing differently. I have create Automation credentials which just contain my SQL username and SQL password.

`

```
 $sqlServerName = "servername"
 $SqlCredentialAsset="AutomationCredentials"



   $sqlCred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name  $SqlCredentialAsset
    $sqlContext = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $sqlServerName -Credential $sqlCred
    Set-AzureSqlDatabase -ConnectionContext $sqlContext -ServerName  -DatabaseName "test" -NewDatabaseName "test_rename"`
```

**EDIT**

The steps I had to add to get Joys script to run from my current set up was:

- Add a 'Run As Account' in automation, (an option currently under account settings in automation)
- Update the azure powershell modules to the latest update under the automation modules section
- Ensure that I used the Azure name for the db server not SSMS name (school boy error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create a RunBook that I can use for renaming an Azure DB for integration test purposes.

If this is your final goal, just try the script in your powershell runbook, it works fine on my side.

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "joywebapp" -ServerName "joydb" -DatabaseName "joydb3" -NewName "joydb2"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy thanks for the reply. I am new to PS in Azure and have found there seems to be 3 flavours of connection, Azure,Azure Classic and ServicePrincipal. I have no Appid so am using Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId "xxxx" -SubscriptionId "xxxx" -Credential $Cred Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $RG -ServerName $svr -DatabaseName $DB1 -NewName $DB2 . The error I now get is : Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'NewName'. Looking at the Docs I can see it's there . Is it a tier problem?, we are using basic

Comment: @RichardH 1. Actually you should have a service principal(the Appid as you said), if you create an automation account, it will create a service principal for you and assign a contributor role to your SP under the subscription automatically. So just run my complete script. 2. To fix the issue, make sure you have installed the `AzureRm` powershell module in your automation account, if it has been installed, try to update the moudel, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-update-azure-modules#update-azure-modules-in-the-azure-portal).

Comment: I cannot update the modules until I create an Azure Azure 'Run As Account' so just trying to sort that out. What url do I use when having to create the Application . For the HomePage and Identifierurls, I am mindful of security issues ....?

Comment: @RichardH As I said, if you have an automation account, you dont need to create the app manually, just try my complete script. I could not help you to get start with azure ad here, it will be a long conversation, you need to check the doc by yourself.

Comment: I have made progress and created am Azure 'Run as account' , I am now down to the issue that -DatabaseName DB cant be found when it hits the Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase statement, I suspect because its a SQL Login as opposed to windows on the db ...

Comment: Ok, now works. I will +1 for answer as put me on correct track and edit the original question to add what else was required.